# Where does Solaris 10 keep a log of pfexec attempts?

Tags: logging, solaris, audit, solaris-10

I assigned a user the "User Security" profile so that they could reset user passwords and unlock accounts.

Does Solaris keep a record of whenever users execute pfexec?

I didn't see any records in `/var/adm/messages`. I didn't see anything in the audit logs using `praudit <audit_log_file> | grep pfexec`.

Answer (score 2):

Found it logged under audit class `as`. Then using:

```
auditreduce -c as <audit_log_file> | praudit | grep "profile command"
```